# Angular- Possible to create a FormGroup from a non-predefined object?

Tags: angular, forms

So, usually when building FormGroups in angular, you usually know how to label or name each field or FormControl because again, usually, you know the properties that your form has to control and validate beforehand. So for example, for a previously known `myHouse` object, I could do:

```
myHouse = new FormGroup({
  door: [''],
  size: [''],
  windows: new FormGroup({
    size: [''],
    clarity: ['']
    ...
  });
})
```

You get the idea. But I am currently creating a component that I want to use as my app's side Filter bar. The key is that I want this component to be re-usable, and because of the needs of this flow, it works like this:

- A parent component builds an array of objects that I have named `filterPreferences`, and passes it to my Filter component who receives it as an @Input(). The object will look like this:

  ```
    this.filterPreferences = [{
      filterName: 'status',
      filterKey: 'Estado',
      options: [
        {
          optionName: 'open',
          optionKey: 'Abierta'
        },
        {
          optionName: 'closed',
          optionKey: 'Cerrada'
        },
        {
          optionName: 'ended',
          optionKey: 'Finalizada'
        }
      ]
  ```

  ... and more objects after this.
  }]
- In this array of objects, filterName refers to the type of parameter, whereas optionName refers to the different options that said parameter can have (an item's **status** could be **open**, **closed** or **ended**). The filterKey and optionKey properties used for i18l translations.
- The child component (Filter component) will receive that array of objects and build a FormGroup or FormArray based on it, so that when the user has finished choosing a series of filters, the Child component can pass that selection back to its respective parent.

The crux here is that my component cannot know the fields or parameters from the start, as with the example of the `house` FormGroup earlier. Different parent components could pass different info blocks to this component. Every parent component will use the same structure of filterNames, filterKeys, optionNames and so on, but the number of entries and names of each parameter will be different for each.

Trying to illustrate my (failed) attempts with a sort of pseudocode, what I feel that I should do is something along the lines of:

-- in my declarations, const formArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);

```
createForm() {
  this.filterPreferences.forEach((item) => {
    const optionNames = item.options.map(( opt ) => opt.optionName);
    item.FilterName = new FormGroup({
      optionNames = new FormControl('');
    })
    this.formArray.push(item.filterName);
  )}
}
```

Essentially iterating over my `filterPreferences` object or array of objects, and building a formGroup for every object. The html for this form would look like this:

```
      <div class="filters" [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let filter of filterPreferences">
          <div class="filter-options">
            <h4>{{filter.filterKey}}</h4>
            <div *ngFor="let options of filter.options">
              <app-checkbox-input
              formControlName="{{options.optionName}}"
              class="float-left mr-3 mb-3"
              [label]=" options.optionKey ">
              </app-checkbox-input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
</div>
```

How do I work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I got most of it solved.

A major mistake that I had is not realizing that, effectively, each of my 'options' block was being created inside its own `formGroup`. So a key element that I was missing was:

```
      <div class="filters" [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let filter of filterPreferences">
          <div class="filter-options">
       ---- a new div for the formGroups ------
            <div formGroupName="{{filter.filterName}}">

            <h4>{{filter.filterKey}}</h4>
            <div *ngFor="let options of filter.options">
              <app-checkbox-input
              formControlName="{{options.optionName}}"
              class="float-left mr-3 mb-3"
              [label]=" options.optionKey ">
              </app-checkbox-input>
            </div>
            </div>
       ----- end of the new div -----
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
```

Note the reference for **formGroupname** inside the new div.

With this, for example, in the following  block:

```
  filterName: 'status',
  filterKey: 'Estado',
  options: [
    {
      optionName: 'open',
      optionKey: 'Abierta'
    },
    {
      optionName: 'closed',
      optionKey: 'Cerrada'
    },
    {
      optionName: 'ended',
      optionKey: 'Finalizada'
    }
  ]
```

My .ts creates this formgroup:

```
status: this.formBuilder.group({
  open: [''],
  closed: [''],
  ended: ['']
})
```

My html can then iterate over its `"let options of filter.options"` and, because the reference to the formGroupName is outside of that ngFor loop, the name to said formGroupName remains intact.